# jQuery datepicker not appearing, race condition?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I formerly had my datepicker appearing when I was applying it to a static element, but for some reason I can't get it to work dynamically. Under certain configurations, it works if I pop up an alert box first. What is wrong?

```
div.load(url, function() {
    div.children().each( function(){this.datepicker({dateFormat:"yy-m-d"}});    
    div.appendTo("div#foos_container");
});
```

Here is some more context:

Javascript:

```
   add_foo = function(url) {
    // Clickable
    var numfoos = $("div#foos_container > div.foo").length + 1;
    var foo_id = numfoos + "-foo";
    var div = $("<div></div>").attr("id",foo_id).addClass("foo");
    div.load(url, function() {
        div.children().each(function(){ 
            // what do expect this to be below? 
            // this will be a child element here, so need
            // to wrap to get a jQuery object
            $(this).datepicker({dateFormat:"yy-m-d"}); 
        });        
    div.appendTo("div#foos_container");
});
```

HTML:

```
<a id="add_foo" onclick="add_foo('{% url add-foo %}')" class="ajax_link">Add Foo</a>

   <div id="foos_container">

   </div>
```

Thank you!

EDIT: Added context. I should note that the HTML is a django template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
div.load(url, function() {
        div.children().each(function(){ 
            // what do expect this to be below? 
            // this will be a child element here, so need
            // to wrap to get a jQuery object
            $(this).datepicker({dateFormat:"yy-m-d"}); 
        });        
        div.appendTo("#foos_container");
});
```

In light of your edit, try the following.

```
add_foo = function(url) {
    // Clickable
    var numfoos = $("#foos_container > div.foo").length + 1;
    var foo_id = numfoos + "-foo";
    var div = $("<div></div>").attr("id",foo_id).addClass("foo");

    div.appendTo("#foos_container").load(url, function() {
        div.children().each(function(){ 
        // what do expect this to be below? 
        // this will be a child element here, so need
        // to wrap to get a jQuery object
        $(this).datepicker({dateFormat:"yy-m-d"}); 
    });        

};
```

What do you expect the `this` to be in `div.children().each( ...)` ?

**EDIT:**

Here's a **[Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/omugu)** which simulates what I believe you are trying to achieve. Add */edit* to the URL to see the code and play with it (example below).

```
<a id="add">Click me to add a div via AJAX Load</a>
<div id="foos_container"></div>

$(function() {

    $('#add').click(function() {

        var numfoos = $("#foos_container > div.foo").length + 1;
        var foo_id = numfoos + "-foo";
        var div = $("<div></div>").attr("id",foo_id).addClass("foo");

        div.appendTo("#foos_container").load("http://jsbin.com/ejalo", function() {
            div.children().each(function(){ 
                $(this).datepicker({dateFormat:"yy-m-d"}); 
            });                
        });                 
    });

});
```

Comment: Hmm it still doesn't work. I'm just attaching it to a div that contains a bunch of these forms that need a date attached to them.

Comment: Is this code running before the datepicker script is declared or before the `document` is ready (finished loading) i.e. is this code either at the bottom of `<body>` or inside of `$(document).ready(function() { /* code here */ });` ?

Comment: No it's an Ajax call initiated by clicking a link. I very much appreciate your efforts!

Comment: I added some more context. The div is newly created. Should I change that? I think I'll try it.

Answer (score 1):

try this in your `$(function(){});`:

```
$('input').filter('.datepicker').datepicker();
```

i don't think you need any of that other garbage, eg `each`, `load` and all that. just the `filter` in your doc.ready function.

Comment: Thank you, you both had part of the solution!